# Ralink RT5572 based wireless adapter not working in AP mode in 5 GHz band with DFS

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-driver, hostapd, dual-band

**Objective:**

Get a CSL USB 2.0 WLAN adapter work in AP mode in the 5 GHz band, in a Linux-based system (in particular, Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, kernel 4.13).
The USB adapter is based on a chipset from Ralink, namely RT5572, as per the output of the `lsusb` command:

```
(...)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter
(...)
```

**Problem:**

I've partially achieved my objective: I'm able to set the adapter as an AP in the 5 GHz band for channels 36, 38, ... up to 48, by setting the variable `channel` in the `hostapd.conf` file, as shown below.

```
interface=wlx24050f615114
driver=nl80211
ssid=nikola-tesla
hw_mode=a
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=HT40+
channel=48
country_code=PT
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1           # 1=wpa, 2=wep, 3=both
wpa=2                 # WPA2 only
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK  
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=xxxxxxxxxx
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0
```

However, 'higher' channels don't work. E.g., if I set `channel=52` (or larger), the AP setup fails, with the following error messages from hostapd:

```
hostapd: wlx24050f615114: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (52) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
hostapd: wlx24050f615114: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
```

Note that none of the channels in the 'working' range requires radar detection (i.e., no DFS requirement), as shown by the output of `iw list` below.

```
Band 2:
    Bitrates (non-HT):
        * 6.0 Mbps
        * 9.0 Mbps
        * 12.0 Mbps
        * 18.0 Mbps
        * 24.0 Mbps
        * 36.0 Mbps
        * 48.0 Mbps
        * 54.0 Mbps
    Frequencies:
        * 5170 MHz [34] (disabled)
        * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm)
        * 5190 MHz [38] (20.0 dBm)
        * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm)
        * 5210 MHz [42] (20.0 dBm)
        * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm)
        * 5230 MHz [46] (20.0 dBm)
        * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm)
        * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 15263 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 15263 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 15263 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 15263 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
```

**Questions:**

- Why don't the 5 GHz channels requiring DFS work with this setup?

I have some suspicions, but no idea on how to follow up on them:

**The DFS CAC (Channel Availability Check) time reported by `iw reg get` is 0 ms (shown below)**, while the value given by `iw list` is 60 sec (as shown above).

```
country PT: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (N/A, 27), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

Could this be why channels with DFS requirements don't work? My assumption here is that a max. allowed CAC time of 0 ms blocks every attempt for radar detection.

**There may be further regulatory domain restrictions 'burned' into the device.** I know this issue can happen with Atheros chipsets (e.g., regdomain set in firmware/EEPROM), and that there are workarounds for it (e.g., as in [this example](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032357)). However, I couldn't find a way to check if the same is happening with the RT5572. Is there a way to know if this is what's happening?

- Has anyone been able to get DFS channels to work with Ralink chipsets (e.g., the RT5572)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some further information which may answer my own question.

Only [a few Linux wireless drivers](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hostapd) support Dynamic Frequency Selection (DFS), namely 3: `ath5k` `ath9k` and `ath10k`. 
This feature is referred to as 'Automatic Channel Selection (ACS)' in [other source](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/acs#hostapd_setup).

I've confirmed this by inspecting the source code of wireless drivers in Linux, and noticed that only the `ath*` drivers implement methods such as `ieee80211_radar_detected()`. This may explain why `hostapd` can't set the channel to a value in the DFS range (52 to 140) when the RT5572 chipset is used (note: Linux uses the `rt2800usb` driver to work with the RT5572).